# OSError at /dfa/lkd/link_auth/ [Errno 5] Input/output error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I'm getting an OS error -[Errno 5] Input/output error when I run my Django app on the server by giving the IP address an URL.
the app also contains authentication which shows the following error -> OS error as we close the gunicorn or putty terminal in which gunicorn was running.
The following error doesn't occur if we keep the putty terminal alive in which the gunicorn is running.

Comment: There's not enough information in this question to suggest an answer. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Gunicorn should be run as a deamon, typically under supervisor or something like that.